# Убить задачу, запущенную в Планировщике

Tags: windows, windows-10, task, windows-server-2008-r2, планировщик-задач

Есть 2 общих рабочих компьютера: один - на базе Win2008Server, другой - Win10Pro. Днём - это рабочие машины для нескольких пользователей, на ночь я ставлю расчёты. Счётная программа организована так, что сохраняет данные после каждой успешной итерации (где-то раз в 4 часа) плюс обязательно раз в четверть часа. Так что, если просто снять задачу в TaskManager'е, потеряется результат максимум 15ти минут работы.

Задача поисковая, входные данные к ней добавляются, так что, в теории, она может считать сколь угодно долго, выдавая результаты. Поскольку я далеко не всегда могу запустить программу вечером, а утром её остановить, была создана задача в планировщике: запускать каждый вечер в 17:30, работать 15 часов и вырубать. На 2008server всё работает, как часы. На Win10Pro - запускается, нормально работает, но не вырубается :( Ошибку при этом планировщик возвращает крайне редко, обычно - "0x1". Все настройки задачи - одинаковы, пользователь, под которым проходит запуск - один и тот же, с обычными правами.

К сожалению, перекомпилировать задачу, задав ей время работы, я не могу. Поэтому остаётся 2 варианта:

1. Разобраться, почему Win10 не вырубает задачу
2. Запускать 5 минут спустя времени, когда программа должна быть остановлена, свою программку, которая убьёт задачу.

С первым вопросом, как я понимаю, биться мне самому (но если кто подскажет что-то доброе, буду рад). А вот по второму: программу, которая так делает, я могу помучаться и написать за несколько вечеров, но, может, есть скрипт из пары строк, который просто найдёт по имени и прибьёт её?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы убить процесс в винде надо использовать `taskkill /im <имя процесса>`.
Сносит все процессы с таким именем или маской.

Comment: имя_процесса = name.exe?

Comment: да, имя exe модуля или маску

Comment: в примере notepad.exe, можно запустить-попробовать :)

Comment: Еще флаги есть. /F - принудительно, например

Comment: Спасибо, даже стыдно, в линуксе знаю, а про винду не подумал :(

Comment: Ну все знать невозможно.